# Trying to move two objects at the same time with arrow keys and WASD

Tags: java, animation, graphics, awt, keylistener

Hey guys I am making a game in which characters can be moved with WASD and Arrow keys. I got them to move but i can not make them move at the same time. One can not be moving for the other shape to move. Is there a way to check for WASD and arrow presses simultaneously? Hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
// The "SoccerGame" class.
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SoccerGame extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    //x and y values of the player 1 and 2's character and the ball
    int x1 = 0, y1 = 275, x2 = 780, y2 = 275, xBall = 400, yBall = 275;

    public void init ()
    {
        this.requestFocus ();
        addKeyListener (this);

        //setting size of program
        setSize (800, 550);

    } // init method


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        //Player 1
        g.setColor (Color.red);
        g.fillRect (x1, y1, 30, 30);

        //Player2
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.fillRect (x2, y2, 30, 30);

        //Ball
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (xBall, yBall, 30, 30);

    } // paint method


    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {
        //Moving Player 1 with arrow Keys
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_W)
        {
            y1 = y1 - 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_S)
        {
            y1 = y1 + 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_A)
        {
            x1 = x1 - 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_D)
        {
            x1 = x1 + 10;
        }

        //Moving player 2 with WASD
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_UP)
        {
            y2 = y2 - 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_DOWN)
        {
            y2 = y2 + 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_LEFT)
        {
            x2 = x2 - 10;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode () == e.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            x2 = x2 + 10;
        }



        repaint ();
    }


    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {
    }


    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
} // SoccerGame class
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a KeyListener (as you have been suggested in your other questions).

Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. You will then need to track which keys have been pressed and use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

The `KeyboardAnimation.java` example shows how this can be done.